# python3 multiprocessing.Pool with maxtasksperchild=1 does not terminate

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

When using `multiprocessing.Pool` in python 3.6 or 3.7 with `maxtasksperchild=1`, I noticed that some processes spawned by the pool are hanging and do not quit, even though the callback to their tasks was already executed. As a result, `Pool.join()` will block forever, even though all tasks are finished. In the process tree, running but idle child processes can be seen. The problem does not occur if `maxtasksperchild=None`.

The problem seems to be related to what the callback precisely does. The docs [point out that the callback "should return immediately"](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool), as it will block other threads managing the pool.

A minimal example to reproduce this behavior on my machine is as follows: (Give it a few tries or increase the number of tasks when it does not block forever.)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from os import getpid
from random import random
from time import sleep


def do_stuff():
    pass


def cb(arg):
    sleep(random())  # can be replaced with print('foo')


p = Pool(maxtasksperchild=1)
number_of_tasks = 100  # a value may depend on your machine -- for mine 20 is sufficient to trigger the behavior
for i in range(number_of_tasks):
    p.apply_async(do_stuff, callback=cb)


p.close()
print("joining ... (this should take just seconds)")
print("use the following command to watch the process tree:")
print("    watch -n .2 pstree -at -p %i" % getpid())
p.join()
```

Contrary to what I expected, `p.join()` in the last line will block forever even though `do_stuff` and `cb` were both called 100 times.

I am aware that `sleep(random())` is in violation of the docs, but is `print()` also taking 'too long'? The way the docs are written suggest that a non-blocking callback function is required for performance and efficiency and make not clear that a 'slow' callback function will break the pool entirely.

1. Is `print()` forbidden in any `multiprocessing.Pool` callback function? (How to replace that functionality? What is "returning immediately", what is not?)
2. If yes, should the python documentation be updated to make this clear?
3. If yes, is it good python practice to rely on "fast" execution of python threads? Does this violate the rule that one should not make assumptions on execution order of threads?
4. Should I report this to the python bug tracker?